# Expected identifier, string, or number. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, format

I am having issues compiling some javascript, And it keeps saying Expected identifier, string or number on the 3rd character of the line },100,'linear',function(){

Is there something i'm missing, i think i formated it different but i can't find out where.

```
firstCard_clone.animate({
    'top': firstCard_offset_2.top,
    'left': firstCard_offset_2.left,
  },100,'linear',function(){
    firstCard_clone.remove();
    $firstDeck.children().children().css('visibility','visible');
    done_fc();
  });
```

Comment: Get rid of the comma after `firstCard_offset_2.left`. Its saying identifier expected, because the presence of the comma insinuates that you have more properties to add to the object, but you don't

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma:

```
firstCard_clone.animate({
    'top': firstCard_offset_2.top,
    'left': firstCard_offset_2.left,  // here
}
```

which means it expects another identifier in the object literal.

Comment: another great resource for this: [jshint](http://www.jslint.com/). It's pretty aggressive in its 'error' checking but it's great for code style as well as finding quick errors like this. You can even change the configuration to tolerate certain errors.